# Make a floor reflective in a subtle way, using reflective probes

Tags: unity-game-engine

So far I did achieve reflection with the horrible hack of duplicate geometry, flip it and change the shader so it look like it is a reflection and not the same geometry upside down :)

Now I did realize that Unity free has reflection probes; which seem awesome.

Problem is: I can't wrap my head around how do you make a floor that reflect the environment, and just the floor.
From my understanding, you create a material, push the smoothness to 1, and then place a reflection probe in the scene, and all the materials smooth enough, will basically reflect. I did change every tile in my floor, to use the new reflective material, and it works fine.

Performance wise, I am using realtime, since the game has gameobject placed at certain events in the game; and I need to reflect these objects on the floor, obviously.

How do you optimize the scene, so I won't waste resources? I did see some tutorials online, but none that really explain what settings to change and how to set a scene to be highly optimized; and very little about how do you control reflection from code, while using the custom mode.

Am I good to go as I am now? I see a difference of 1-2 FPS, between when the probe is on and when is off; but that may not be telling the whole story though; so I suspect that things can be optimized.

Comment: So do you plan on running this on a mobile device?

Comment: No, the application is already heavy on the computational part; plus the GI. I am planning probably to limit this to the triad (OSX, Win, Linux)